# Where is combobox.items in avalonia 11

Tags: data-binding, combobox, avaloniaui

Several Days ago,I update my avalonia project to avalonia 11.After that, I find a error information,the combobox data binding

```
<ComboBox .... Items="{Binding version_list}">
```

can't work now.I have searched on avalonia document,but the problem can't be solve,either.

I want to binding a string list to a combobox in avalonia 11.The data template is right, only binding source has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its one of [the breaking changes In V11.0](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Breaking-Changes#itemscontrol-changes-including-all-itemscontrol-inherited-controls-like-listbox-or-menus) . `Items` Property is now Read only to set the collection you can use `ItemsSource` instead of `Items`

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding version_list}"/>
```