The Items property of the Menu component cannot set in avaloniaUI
Background:
I try to use Menu component of avaloniaUI in axaml.
Problem:
The Items property of Menu cannot be set in axaml.I don't know why this happened.
The axaml code is following:
<Menu Items="{Binding Items}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="AliceBlue">
    <Menu.Styles>
        <Style Selector="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Styles>
</Menu>

The main code in code-behind is following:
var menu = new MenuMainViewModel();
menu.MenuItems = new MenuItemViewModel[]
{
    new MenuItemViewModel
    {
        Header="file",
        Items=new MenuItemViewModel[]
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel { 
                Header="startNew", 
            },
        }
    },

};

The error message of Menu component in a XAML is following:

Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Items of type Avalonia.Controls:Avalonia.Controls.itemControl for argument
Avalonia.Markup:Avalonia.Data.Binding, available setter parameter lists are:
Svstem.obieasvstem.0bect line 10, position 9.

Trying :
I find the avalonia's official document for Menu component. The Menu component had Items property as following.

But I don't know why it can't be set.

this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/76753865/9482050
